# JNI NewByteArray memory leak

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I have a Java method that process a bitmap and returns a String.
When I call this method from JNI (VS 2010) it works, but if I call this method many times,
the memory of the process grown up until crash.
The instruction that use a lot of memory is:

```
jbyteArray jBuff = _env->NewByteArray(b->Length);
```

My code:

```
static jobject staticArray=0;

System::String^ MyClass::ExecuteJavaMethod(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmp)
{
    JNIEnv *_env;
    System::String^ out;
    unsigned const char * buff;

    int res = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&_env, NULL);

    if (jvm->GetEnv((void**) &_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
    {
        return "GetEnv ERROR";
    }

    //save the bitmap in the stream
    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
    bmp->Save(ms, ImageFormat::Bmp);

    //get the bitmap buffer
    array<unsigned char>^b = ms->GetBuffer() ;

    //unmanaged conversion
    buff = GetUnmanaged(b,b->Length);


    //fill the buffer
    jbyteArray jBuff = _env->NewByteArray(b->Length);       
    _env->SetByteArrayRegion(jBuff, 0, b->Length, (jbyte*) buff);

    //call the java method
    jstring str = (jstring) _env->CallStaticObjectMethod (  Main,
                                javaMethod,
                                jBuff);



    // _env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jBuff,(jbyte*)buff), 0); //NOT WORKING

    //staticArray= _env->NewGlobalRef(jBuff);  NOT
    //_env->DeleteLocalRef(jBuff);             WORKING  


    //return the string result of the java method
    return gcnew String(env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0));

}
```

Comment: Why did you comment your line which does `_ReleaseByteArrayElements()`?

Comment: because is the same, memory go up and crashes...

Comment: You don't seem to be releasing `buff` at any point. Is `GetUnmanaged` allocating a temporary buffer that never gets reclaimed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

the answer is: `_env->DeleteLocalRef(jBuff);`

Comment: Local references get [freed automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jni/design.html#global-and-local-references). You only need to call `DeleteLocalRef` if you do a lot of work in native code before returning to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call `DetachCurrentThread()` for each `AttachCurrentThread()`, which is requested in [Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). That makes the local references (`jBuff` and `str`) unable to be freed automatically. Also, the `const char*` fetched through `GetStringUTFChars()` needs to be released.

The correct way is change

```
return gcnew String(env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0));
```

into

```
const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0);
System::String^ retstr = gcnew String(cstr);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, cstr);
jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
return retstr;
```